Django is not importing models: Sublime text can't find django. Windows 11
I've been working through Python Crash Course e2, and got stuck on Ch.18.
Having opened models.py, and entered the code, the error message is:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
I have spent some time working on this, without a solution.
Could it be that PCCe2 is out of date, or is there a workaround solution?
ChatGPT has said to make sure to activate the virtual environment, make sure Django is installed; verify the installation; check my Python environment and ensure it is activated; check for multiple Python installations; check the installation path; verify the installation path; check that "models.py" is in the app directory, and the app is listed in the installed apps, etc.
I have tried all of these, and the text editor cannot seem to find the module django. But it is among the files.
Here is the settings, with INSTALLED APPS list:
from pathlib import Path

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # My apps
    'learning_logs',
    # Default django apps
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

This is the line where I get the error:
from django.db import models

Unfortunately, I'm not so sure what is meant by "Related model", hence it's omission.
I will say that in terminal, and error message I got was: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.utils'.
I hope that makes sense.

can you share settıngs.INSTALLED_APPS, related model, and the line where you get the error?

@enesislam, I have edited the question to include your requested details, thank you.

It seems like Django is not installed properly, can you run django-admin --version on a newly opened command line and be sure if Django is installed

It's saying I have version 5.1.3 installed... I ran the command in an (ll_env) virtual environment. Perhaps PCCe2 has a different version of Django??

You can create a Build System for your project where you can specify a python environment to use:
{
    "cmd": ["/full/path/to/your/specific/python", "$file"],
    "selector": "source.python",
    "file_regex": "^\\s*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)"
}

Generally though, you don't need to run any files when working with Django. Just run python manage.py runserver (in a terminal), edit the source files and the app will be reloaded automatically; refresh the browser to see the results.
If you do need to run a standalone script that uses Django, make sure to add django.setup():
import django
django.setup()

# now you can use models and other Django features


Thank you @Igonato, for this nice solution. I have ticked your answer, because in fact, for my purposes, finding the module     django     does not appear to be instrumental in continuing on to getting my project going successfully. If anyone else has had this problem, I suggest powering ahead and ignoring the error message, which in any case is not really an error message at all, it seems!

Glad to be of help @DanielFBest. Sublime Text is a good editor choice for a beginner, you not going to have many bells and whistles, but, also, there are few distraction. One advice I could give - get more comfortable with the terminal. Edit code in sublime, run stuff in the terminal. More often than not, you can set things up to rerun automatically when a file changes, so you can stay in the editor and glance at the terminal after hitting Ctrl+S. If you using cmd.exe, install a better terminal emulator, like the Terminal app from MS Store. Cheers!

Great, @Igonato, thanks for the advice. I certainly am a beginner with web development, and without wanting getting too "chatty", what other editors could you recommend? I already have VS downloaded, from a prior excursion in coding - what are the benefits. Also, I had no idea you could install a better terminal emulator; I'm using Powershell at the moment.

Powershell is a shell. A terminal (emulator, used to be a physical device in the distant past) is the "black window" app that runs a shell inside it, so you can use PS in either terminal. I switched from Sublime to VSCode due to better integration with WSL and a few plugins a while ago, still miss the performance of Sublime. Zed editor is still in somewhat of a beta, but looks very promising. About getting chatty, my spoken English has gotten a bit rusty, If you're up for it, you can add me on Discord (same handle), I can tell you a few things about the web dev and get some practice in return

I forgot if you get an inbox notification if not @ mentioned, so just in case @DanielFBest

thanks! I've sent you a friend request on Discord, so hope to chat with you there, and learn some things!

same thing - @ mentioning you now!!

Trying to @ mention you, @Igonato...
